# PHP Regex Extract Inner Content From Non-Capturing Group

Tags: php, regex, performance

I'm parsing information from a very long HTML table; right now the code I'm using parses using the DOMDocument, DOMElement (etc) classes. I wanted to do a performance test running the current method against Regex'ing the information out of the table but I can't get the right expression.

An HTML row of the table looks like this:

```
<tr><td>   JON SMITH     </td><td> 2000-09-29 </td></tr>
```

And the expression I've been attempting looks something like this:

```
/(?:<td>([a-zA-Z\s]*?)<\/td><td>([0-9-\s]*?)<\/td>)/
```

The issue with the above expression is that it's returning the entire row contents and not just the inner column contents. Ideally the preg_match_all array results would be name, date, name, date etc.

Is this a reasonable thing to do, or should I stick with the DOM technique? If it is reasonable, could someone lend a hand with the regex?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, the RegEx solution has WAY better performance than using the DOM classes; in my situation it's the difference between seconds and minutes.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As mentioned I'm currently parsing using the PHP DOM classes; in a situation like this if RegEx offers better performance I'd be willing to try it. Normally I'd 100% agree with you and stick to a proper HTML parsing option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preg_match_all() and pass the third parameter with the array to fill and the fourth parameter PREG_SET_ORDER.

```
preg_match_all("/(?:<td>([a-zA-Z\s]*?)<\/td><td>([0-9-\s]*?)<\/td>)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The result array should be like this :

```
$matches => array(
   [0] => array(
      [0] => '<td>   JON SMITH     </td><td> 2000-09-29 </td>',
      [1] => '   JON SMITH     ',
      [2] => ' 2000-09-29 '
   ),
   [1] => array(
      [0] => '<td>   JACK BOLD     </td><td> 2000-10-20 </td>',
      [1] => '   JACK BOLD     ',
      [2] => ' 2000-10-20 '
   ),
   ...
);
```

Please refer to [preg_match_all() documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: Ran a performance test, it whomps the proper HTML parsing technique.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

step1. search `<table>...</table>`: 
`/<table[^>]*+>([^<]*+(?:(?!<\/?+table)<[^<]*+)*+)<\/table>/i`

step2. search all `<tr>...</tr>` from step1 group1: 
`/<tr[^>]*+>([^<]*+(?:(?!<\/?+tr)<[^<]*+)*+)<\/tr>/ix`

step3. extract data from every `<td>...</td>`(from step2 group1): 
`/<td[^>]*+>([^<]*+(?:(?!<\/?+td)<[^<]*+)*+)<\/td>/ix`

these terrible patterns refer to `Mastering Regular Expressions 3rd`

sample code:

```
    <?php
$foo = '<tr><td>   JON SMITH     </td><td> 2000-09-29 </td></tr>';
if(preg_match_all('/<td[^>]*+>([^<]*+(?:(?!<\/?+td)<[^<]*+)*+)<\/td>/ix', $foo, $matches) > 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); ++$i)
        printf("%s\n", $matches[0][$i]);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); ++$i)
        printf("%s\n", $matches[1][$i]);
}
?>
```

output:

```
<td>   JON SMITH     </td>
<td> 2000-09-29 </td>
JON SMITH
2000-09-29
```

Comment: I ran a test and while it certainly does work (and works well), it's a little less elegant and offers slightly poorer performance than the answer above. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: really? I tested my sample code again with RegexBuddy. Match found in 18 steps. But another solution need 118 steps :P. Basically, my pattern combines unrolling loop technique with possessive quantifiers, it should be a fastest solution.